# Jquery DatePicker doesn`t work when adding InnerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I have a date picker and when I add the datepicker using `innerHTML`, it doesn't work.

```
while (currentMovedAmount < movedAmount)
{
    currentMovedAmount++;
    movedInContainer.innerHTML += extraAddresses.innerHTML;
    movedInContainer.innerHTML += '<hr>';
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
}
```

This is the html that is being added. i have read in places just to re-assign the datepicker but still no luck, i tried to add an event on focus as well but still doesn't work.

```
<p>Postcode: <INPUT name="postCode"  id="postCode"  type="text" placeholder="Enter Postcode"></p>   
<p>Date Moved In <INPUT name="dateMovedIn" id="dateMovedIn1"  type="text" class="datepicker"></p>
```

**Update**
Mistake on spelling datepicker
i can get it working if i assign the to the id, however if the ids are the same will this stop the datepicker working from class?

**Soultion**
Don't use the class ".datepicker"

Comment: Which datepicker plugin are you using? Can you create a JSFiddle?

Comment: could be due to class name typo, in html it is 'datepicker' but in js it is 'datepick'?

Comment: Hope you dont call javascript code before drawing the input.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this could be due to class name typo, in html you declared class as 'datepicker' but in js you called as 'datepick'?

```
//js
$( function() {
    $("#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    $('#dynamic').html('Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker">');
    $(".datepicker" ).datepicker();
});

//html
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<p id='dynamic'></p>
```

Find the below fiddle solution for reference - created using static and dynamic addition of html both work without any flaw.

http://jsfiddle.net/b68Xb/2621/